# How is it possible to control hardwares like Parallel port and serial port from asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, hardware, lpt

Guyz, please tell me if i can control a LPT port or COM port or any other hardware of server using ASP.Net with C#. I haven't found any clue in the internet.

I want to control a COM port Parallel port from web application. I want to know about this urgently.
Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to rethink whatever you are trying to doing if you are planning to access the port during an asp.net request.

http://logix4u.net/Legacy_Ports/Parallel_Port/How_Inpout32.dll_works_.html

Answer (score 0):

Can you control a Parallel or Serial Port from .NET? Yes. 
I would recommend against doing this in ASP.NET though.

Another SO question with some helpers on using inpout32/64 for Parallel port access: [C# LPT inpout32.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607935/c-lpt-inpout32-dll)