# How to read and write data from a LPT in C#?

Tags: c#, printing, lpt

I did some research around, some of the answers suggest using inpout32.dll, I tried it in C#, it always return 255 whenever I read from any address. [sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607935/c-sharp-lpt-inpout32-dll).

All I want to do is to read from 0x379 when my printer is power on and off, see if I can get two sets of different data, hence I can tell the printer is on or off!(I don't know if this will work, let me know if u know it won't work!)

If u happens to know any other way around to accomplish the task, please share it with me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622903/how-do-i-check-if-a-printer-is-installed-and-ready-using-c/1622931#1622931

Comment: @Blorgbeard it won't work, because my printer is not a standard printer, there is no driver for it.

Comment: Ah, I see. Then I can't help you, sorry :)